# How to troubleshoot Localytics installation for PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm building a PhoneGap application for a client. They want Localytics integrated as their analytics package.

However, every time I try to install the Localytics plugin, with 
`<plugin name="localytics-cordova" />`
in my `config.xml`, I receive the following error:

`Error - Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from your app): Fetching plugin "localytics-cordova" via npm Installing "com.localytics.phonegap.LocalyticsPlugin" at "5.4.0" for ios Failed to install 'com.localytics.phonegap.LocalyticsPlugin': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 at ChildProcess.whenDone (/private/tmp/gimlet/3418551/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16) at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11) at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13) at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12) pod: Command failed with exit code 1 - You can fix this here`

The guidance for this error states that I should delete plugin files from my app. I'm using PhoneGap Build, the plugins are installed at compile time, I have no plugin files in my app at all. I am finding very little documentation for this configuration at all. Anyone out there familiar with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, version 5.4.0 of `localytics-cordova` does not seem to install under PhoneGap (any version as far as I could tell, but I did not exhaustively test) for iOS.

Version 5.2.0 DOES seem to install. Why Localytics support was incapable of providing this answer, I'm really not sure. So,

`<plugin name="localytics-cordova" />` in your `config.xml` will fail.

`<plugin name="localytics-cordova"  spec="~5.2.0" />` seems to work.